# How to do multiple update queries in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am wanting to update each column `oneToFive` (which is a number from one to five) when I delete an entry in my table:

so my table looks like this

```
|oneToFive|name|
----------------
|1        |a   |
|2        |b   |
|3        |c   |
|4        |d   |
|5        |e   |
```

Say if I delete the row with name d the table will then look like:

```
|oneToFive|name|
----------------
|1        |a   |
|2        |b   |
|3        |c   |
|5        |e   |
```

I want it to look like:

```
|oneToFive|name|
----------------
|1        |a   |
|2        |b   |
|3        |c   |
|4        |e   |
```

The table also may not be full for example it could be like:

```
|oneToFive|name|
----------------
|1        |a   |
|2        |b   |
|3        |c   |
```

and if I deleted a I would want it like:

```
|oneToFive|name|
----------------
|1        |b   |
|2        |c   |
```

So I have tried this crazy code where I write all the update querys followed by executing the ones that exist after deleting the row. But this doesn't work.

```
//find query
if($result === 5){

}else if($result === 4){
    $query2 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='4'
    WHERE oneToFive='5'";
}else if($result === 3){
    $query3 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='3'
    WHERE oneToFive='4'";
    $query2 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='4'
    WHERE oneToFive='5'";
}else if($result === 2){
    $query4 ="UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='2'
    WHERE oneToFive='3'";
    $query3 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='3'
    WHERE oneToFive='4'";
    $query2 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='4'
    WHERE oneToFive='5'";
}else {
    $query5 ="UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='1'
    WHERE oneToFive='2'";
    $query4 ="UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='2'
    WHERE oneToFive='3'";
    $query3 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='3'
    WHERE oneToFive='4'";
    $query2 = "UPDATE faveMonth
    SET oneToFive='4'
    WHERE oneToFive='5'";
}

//run querys
if($result === 5){

}else if($result === 4){
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query2))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
}else if($result === 3){
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query2))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }

    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query3))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
}else if($result === 2){
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query2))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }

    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query3))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query4))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
}else {
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query2))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }

    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query3))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query4))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
    if(mysqli_query ($con,$query5))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            die("error updating other row(s)");  
        }
}
```

Can you think of any better ways to do this?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? If the number has no significance, you might as well not store it at all and just use a counter when you get your rows.

Comment: Why?  Let your primary key stay your primary key -- dont' try to update it.  If you need a `row_number`, then create a view with it using user-defined variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single statement like this

```
UPDATE faveMonth SET oneToFive = oneToFive - 1 WHERE oneToFive > x
```

once you removed the entry with `oneToFive == x`

Comment: @jeroen thx! I do agree with your comment. But I had a similar case with saving a user set order and so without much context hope I can provide an useful answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop instead of using a chain of `if else`.

Example:

```
 $result = ... // result from query
 $count = ... // number of results in query

 for ($i = 1; $i++; $i < $count)
 {
     // update $result[$i]'s oneToFive with $i
 }
```

This is not a full implementation, just an idea.

It isn't very efficient, you should go with `kingkero`'s solution.